Using the Shift Key in .XCompose file
I'm trying to use Linux as my main OS and, since I've an italian layout keyobard, I've added some custom key sequences to the .XCompose file.
However some of them seems to not working, specifically the ones using the Left/Right Shift key.
In my .XCompose file I have this line
<Multi_key> <Shift_L> <egrave>: "{" U+007B  which should allow me to type a curly bracket when using the compose key with left shift and the e-grave key.
However this is not working. Is something I'm missing here?
